# c# foreach file in a directory but in a specific order

Tags: c#, foreach

I'm making a journal application for myself in c# where i can make journals with dates attached to it.
I'm using a foreach statement to let the data display in the textboxes. I can't figure out how to display the journals in order (old->new) with the dates in Textbox3 (t3). I live in Europe so It's DD/MM/YYYY. I hope it's clear, thanks.

```
string[] journalfolder = Directory.GetDirectories(@"D:\panel\Journal\", "*");
        foreach (string file in journalfolder)
        {
            Color grey = new Color();

            TextBox t1 = new TextBox();
            t1.Name = "t1_" + (t1.Controls.Count + 1);
            t1.Location = new Point(265, 20);
            grey = Color.FromArgb(31, 31, 31);
            t1.Width = 332;
            t1.BackColor = grey;
            t1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
            t1.ForeColor = Color.White;
            try
            {
                string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(file + @"\text.txt");
                t1.Text = lines[0];
            }
            catch { }

            TextBox t2 = new TextBox();
            t2.Name = "t2_" + (t2.Controls.Count + 1);
            t2.Location = new Point(265, 39);
            t2.Width = 332;
            t2.Height = 155;
            grey = Color.FromArgb(31,31,31);
            t2.BackColor = grey;
            t2.Multiline = true;
            t2.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
            t2.ForeColor = Color.White;
            try
            {
                using (var sr = new StreamReader(file + @"\text.txt"))
                {
                    
                    string line;
                    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        t2.Text = line;
                    }
                    
                }

            }
            catch { }
            
            TextBox t3 = new TextBox();
            t3.Name = "t3_" + (t3.Controls.Count + 1);
            t3.Location = new Point(265, 199);
            grey = Color.FromArgb(31, 31, 31);
            t3.Width = 332;
            t3.BackColor = grey;
            t3.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
            t3.ForeColor = Color.White;
            try
            {
                string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(file + @"\date.txt");
                t3.Text = lines[0];
            }
            catch { }

            Panel image = new Panel();
            image.Name = "image" + (image.Controls.Count + 1);
            image.Location = new Point(20, 20);
            image.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Zoom;
            image.Width = 223;
            image.Width = 192;
            try
            {
                string supportedExtensions = "*.jpg,*.gif,*.png,*.bmp,*.jpe,*.jpeg,*.wmf,*.ico,*.eps,*.tif,*.tiff";
                foreach (string imageFile in Directory.GetFiles(file + @"\Files", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(s => supportedExtensions.Contains(Path.GetExtension(s).ToLower())))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(imageFile);
                    image.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(imageFile);
                    
                }
                
            }
            catch { }
            

            Panel p = new Panel();
            p.Name = "panel" + (flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Count + 1);
            p.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(49,49,49);
            p.Width = 628;
            p.Height = 236;
            p.Controls.Add(t1);
            p.Controls.Add(t2);
            p.Controls.Add(t3);
            p.Controls.Add(image);
            flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(p);

        }
```

[image: form with journals displayed]

Comment: Your code looks a bit too messy, first of all. It is hard to read and I am sure will be also hard to maintain later on. First what I would suggest is to use methods for make the similar code stay in one place. Second suggestion, is to never do catch an exception without handling it somehow. Its just after very short overview of your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not quite sure I understand your requirement correctly, but I'll give it a try ...

The date is managed in a date.txt file. It contains the date in the format DD/MM/YYYY, correct?

```cs
DateTime timestamp = DateTime.Parse("ValueFromFile");
```

It is best to put the title, text and date in a class or struct. Maybe something like this:

```cs
public class Data
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
}
```

You should put all the elements you have read into a list or a dictionary before displaying them on the UI and processing them further. Once all the data is in this list, you can easily sort it by date using LINQ.

```cs
List<Data> values = new List<Data>();
// TODO
// Add the items

foreach (Data item in values.OrderBy((item) => item.Timestamp))
{
}

// Or
foreach (Data item in values.OrderByDescending((item) => item.Timestamp))
{
}
```